# ArcGIS Web AppBuilder widget config?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, json, arcgis-web-appbuilder, configuration

I downloaded a webapp builder template (javascript) that I've placed on my own web server and is running fine.

However, I am not able to modify the widgets in the config.json file to the settings that I want.

For instance, I want the "Coordinate" widget to have meters instead of feet, however, when I adjust the config.json file in the widget file, these changes aren't reflect.

Has anyone encountered this issue?

I read the webapp builder documentation (http://doc.arcgis.com/en/web-appbuilder/extend-apps/coordinate.htm) but can't seem to figure it out.

This is the json in the current config file (for the app itself, not just the widget):

```
  {
    "label": "Coordinate",
    "uri": "widgets/Coordinate/Widget",
    "position": {
      "left": 200,
      "bottom": 20
    },
    "config": {}
  }
```

This is the json in the widget config file:

```
{
  "outputunit": "dms",
  "spatialReferences": []
}
```

The latter says DMS but the units still show up as feet.

Comment: Why not just edit the widget from the AppBuilder? You can specify what units will be used for the coordinates there. Widgets tab > Coordinate. You can even add output coordinate system if you have your data overlay in another spatial reference (and specify what units you want to have).

Comment: @alex-tereshenkov, but after configuring the app, can I download it and host it on my own web server? From what I have found, if you configure the app on ArcGIS Online using their web builder, it has to be hosted on AGO.

Comment: Oh yes, I've done this without any problem. You just need to click Download in the Web AppBuilder main window for the application you want to host. You will get a .zip file with all the contents which you can host (I've used IIS).

Comment: @alex-tereshenkov , Is this only available if you're part of the beta community for the app builder? I'm using the Beta app builder on ArcGIS online organizational account and there is no download option for the apps you create and save.

Comment: You have stated in the question that "I downloaded a webapp builder template (javascript) that I've placed on my own web server and is running fine." Which is why I've thought you are working with the local version. I have access to the beta and yes, you need access to this to get your app downloaded so you could make modifications.

Comment: Ohh okay! Sorry about that, Alex. My mistake.Thank you for clarifying though. Do you know how to go about modifying the webapp builder template (that's downloadable through AGO) to reflect what I mentioned in the original post?

Comment: Not really, never done that.. Cannot really help you with that.

Comment: Not a problem, Alex. Was able to sort it out here: https://geonet.esri.com/message/427427#427427
Thanks for the suggestions though!

Answer (score 5):

In the Web AppBuilder for ArcGIS (Developer Edition), after modifying the configuration of the Coordinate Widget in a local application and ensuring that you've saved your work, the settings can be found/manipulated here

```
apps\[number]\widgets\Coordinate\config_Coordinate.json
```

Comment: John, this will make a change to published app [number]'s widget config. Is there a way to tell WAB to look for changes to the source widget code or config, from the `\client\stemapp\widgets` directory? [Asking for a friend](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131058/how-to-refresh-the-code-in-a-web-appbuilder-widget)