# How to update the source code for apps built with ArcGIS Web AppBuilder widgets?

Tags: node-js, arcgis-web-appbuilder

What is the procedure for updating a widget's code, in an app built using the [ArcGIS Web AppBuilder](https://developers.arcgis.com/web-appbuilder/)?

I'm editing a widget which is working correctly. When I reload an app which uses this widget, I'm not seeing the changes. This includes using CTRL-F5 and > History > Clear All.

I can see from the file system that the changes I made in the the source directory `C:\arcgis-web-appbuilder-1.0\client\stemapp\widgets....` have not flowed through to the app's directory (`C:\arcgis-web-appbuilder-1.0\server\apps\31\widgets...`) which strongly suggests that a Node-level process is required (and explains why F5 has no effect).

Deleting the app from the Web AppBuilder main page, and creating a new app, does use the new code. Presumably a new app always fetches the latest source code.

Is there a shortcut method? I'm hoping there might be something in Node.js to tell all apps to update their source code, but I'm a Node.js novice and don't know where to start.

I'm trying [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon#nodemon) which says "nodemon will watch the files *in the directory in which nodemon was started*, and if any files change, nodemon will automatically restart your node application."

The startup.bat file launches node in the `/server` subdirectory, which might explain why the widget files in the `/client` subdirectory are not being tracked. I can't figure out how to start nodemon one level up, so that both subdirectories are monitored.

*(Cross-posted to https://geonet.esri.com/message/450805)*

Comment: http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3802/how-to-raise-same-question-on-different-stack-exchange-sites/3804#3804

Comment: Brand new product support is likely best answered on the product support forum... that's where I'd put my money.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So far I haven't seen any way to "refresh" the app's widget code automatically or programatically.

A workaround was suggested by [Larry Stout](https://geonet.esri.com/message/451832#451832):

- add your widget code to `\arcgis-web-appbuilder-1.0\client\stemapp\widgets` then create an app.
- this will build a new app containing a snapshot of your widget code (eg `\arcgis-web-appbuilder-1.0\server\apps\APP_NUMBER\widgets`
- edit this snapshot code directly in your code editor, and test it at http://localhost:3344/webappbuilder/apps/APP_NUMBER
- to deploy the changes, overwrite the code in `\arcgis-web-appbuilder-1.0\client\stemapp\widgets`
- any new apps will use the updated code